# mariadb alternative to outer apply or lateral?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

What I wanted was to use CROSS APPLY, but I guess that doesn't exist in mysql. The alternative I've read is LATERAL. Well, I'm using mariadb 10.3 and I guess that doesn't exist either. The ticket table contains an id that's referenced by the ticket_id column in the note table. A ticket can have many notes, I'm trying to list all tickets with their most recent note date (post_date). How could I write the query below for mariadb?

```
SELECT t.*, n.post_date
FROM ticket t,
LATERAL (
    SELECT note.post_date FROM note WHERE t.id = note.ticket_id ORDER BY note.post_date DESC LIMIT 1
) n;
```

Example table structure:

**Ticket**

| id | subject |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | stuff |
| 2 | more |

**note**

| id | post_date | ticket_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 1 |
| 2 |  | 1 |
| 3 |  | 2 |
| 4 |  | 1 |
| 5 |  | 2 |

I did find an open jira ticket from people asking for mariadb to support lateral.

Comment: For those interested in the tickets for this: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19078 and https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-6373

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I read, `LATERAL` will not be supported in MariaDB until version 11.  But we can just as easily use `ROW_NUMBER` here, which is supported:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id ORDER BY post_date DESC) rn
    FROM note
)

SELECT t.*, n.post_date
FROM ticket t
INNER JOIN cte n
    ON n.ticket_id = t.id
WHERE n.rn = 1;
```

If you wanted a close translation of your current lateral join, then use:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
    (SELECT n.post_date
     FROM note n
     WHERE t.id = note.ticket_id
     ORDER BY n.post_date DESC
     LIMIT 1)
FROM ticket t;
```

Comment: I couldn't get your WITH example to work, giving me syntax error somewhere. But your later example works. Would there be a performance difference between the two?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the first query which is fixed now.  You should probably use the first query.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed the missing  parenthesis right after I posted.