# Can LATERAL JOIN have a pivot table subquery in MariaDB 10.6?

Tags: time-series, mariadb, lateral-join

I am trying to join data from two tables by nearest earliest date. The first tables dates are more frequent than the seconds dates. I came across a few links and it seems like a Lateral Join may provide what I need:

1. https://jonmce.medium.com/what-the-heck-is-a-lateral-join-anyway-4c3345b94a63
2. [SQL: join with an equal key and nearest key (similar to Pandas's merge as of)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58487697/sql-join-with-an-equal-key-and-nearest-key-similar-to-pandass-merge-as-of)

The first table, (Table A) and is the correct dimension i.e number of rows.

| date | code | multiplier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 - 01 -01 | c1 | .3 |
| 2018 - 01 -01 | c2 | .5 |
| 2018 - 01 -01 | c3 | .2 |
| 2018 - 06 -01 | c1 | .4 |
| 2018 - 06 -01 | c1 | .4 |
| 2018 - 06 -01 | c3 | .2 |
| 2019 - 01 -01 | c1 | 1 |
| 2019 - 06 -01 | c1 | .5 |
| 2019 - 06 -01 | c2 | .5 |
| 2020 - 01 -01 | c1 | .3 |
| 2020 - 01 -01 | c2 | .5 |
| 2020 - 01 -01 | c3 | .2 |

However, the second table needs to be pivoted before it can be mapped on the first table.

| date | Item | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 - 01 -01 | A | 1 |
| 2018 - 01 -01 | B | 2 |
| 2018 - 01 -01 | C | 2 |
| 2019 - 01 -01 | A | 2 |
| 2019 - 01 -01 | B | 3 |
| 2019 - 01 -01 | C | 4 |
| 2020 - 01 -01 | A | 4 |
| 2020 - 01 -01 | B | 4 |
| 2020 - 01 -01 | C | 5 |

My attempt at using LATERAL JOIN...

```
SELECT 
  A.*, C.*
FROM ( 
   SELECT
         `j`.`id`,
         `j`.`date`,
         `k`.`key`,
         `k`.`value`
   FROM `j`
       INNER JOIN `k` ON `j`.`id` = `k`.`id`
       WHERE `j`.`guid` = '<filter>'
) AS A
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT `B`.*
   FROM (
         SELECT
         'rate'.`date`,
         MIN( CASE WHEN `rate`.`item` = 'itemA' THEN `rate`.`cost` END) 'itemA',
         MIN( CASE WHEN `rate`.`item` = 'itemB' THEN `rate`.`cost` END) 'itemB',
         MIN( CASE WHEN `rate`.`item` = 'itemC' THEN `rate`.`cost` END) 'itemC'
         FROM `rate`
         GROUP BY `rate`.`date`) AS B
   WHERE `B`.`date` <= `A`.`date`
   ORDER BY `B`.`date` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `C` ON true
);
```

The result should just have the values of the pivoted tables new columns with some duplication. But I am getting a syntax error
Schema Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( SELECT `B`.* FROM ( SELECT 'rate'.`date`, MIN'

| date | code | multiplier | A | B | C | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 - 01 -01 | c1 | .3 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2018-01-01 |
| 2018 - 01 -01 | c2 | .5 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2018-01-01 |
| 2018 - 01 -01 | c3 | .2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2018-01-01 |
| 2018 - 06 -01 | c1 | .4 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2018-01-01 |
| 2018 - 06 -01 | c2 | .4 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2018-01-01 |
| 2018 - 06 -01 | c3 | .2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2018-01-01 |

I pretty sure I can do this using python and pandas or spark, but I'd prefer to keep this in SQL and I like the cleanliness of the Lateral Join. I do know that table 1 (A) works and so does Table B (The pivot). The issue is putting table B inside of the Lateral Join is where my issue is arising.

Comment: You're missing `CASE WHEN` inside each `MIN()`

Comment: Whoops @Barmar,  you are correct in that when I was copying it over. I have the CASE WHEN in the actual query. I will make the revision.

Comment: If you can use LATERAL then you can use CTE and window functions. Try to use them - it may be more fast and clear.

Comment: It works in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xh1wmjzr). I was able to reproduce similar error when `from` clause was malformed.

Comment: Interesting @PonderStibbons that it works for you in dbfiddle. When I put it in I am given the same response I see in workbench

`Schema Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( SELECT `B`.* FROM ( SELECT 'rate'.`date`, MIN' at line 10` 

Only difference is that in workbench the error is a couple lines later, same error though..

Comment: But as you see it works. So please post your fiddle so we can look at it, there must be something small in syntax.

Comment: @PonderStibbons, I think I realized the issue. I have been saying mysql, maybe because I've been using mysql workbench. The DB is actually mariadb 10.6. If I change your dbfiddle to mariadb 10.6 then you will see what I see.

Comment: Lateral isn't expected until MariaDB 11. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74580079/mariadb-alternative-to-outer-apply-or-lateral

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, it looks I'll have to look at CTE and window functions.